# Postgres does not use default float value

Tags: postgresql

My table has these columns:

```
priority double precision DEFAULT 0.5::double precision, 
created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
```

But for the record that was just inserted the value is null:

[image]

Why doesn't it work?

**Update:**
I've updated the flask-sqlalchemy row to:

```
priority = db.Column(db.Float, server_default=u'0.5', nullable=False)
```

and the table shows:

> priority double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.5::double precision,

but now it gives the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) null value in
>   column "priority" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Presumably, your client process explicitly sent a `NULL`. How are you doing the insert?

Comment: Please show us the complete `Insert` statement you are using. And you probably do not want `double`, for details see: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

In the database add a `NOT NULL` constraint to the column. So you will notice when the client try to insert a null value:

```
priority double precision DEFAULT 0.5::double precision NOT NULL,
```

In the client use the keyword `DEFAULT` instead of null when doing insert:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (priority, created) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

See the official documentation for more info: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: Yes, you can see now a error message because you try to insert a null value. Now you need to adjust the code which does the insert (see my answer). Add to the question the code responsible for the INSERT